# Select2 destroying itself when adding another element to DOM

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, select, jquery-select2

I have a form with a single select field. I have attached select2 to it. Through Javascript I'm adding/removing more such fields in the client itself. Randomly, one of the added fields loses the select2 functionality.

**JS Fiddle**: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hahaidontknowmyname/9vsfyqck/21/)

**To reproduce**: Click on `Add more` twice. Now click on `Remove` of the field that was added first (i.e. the second field in the list). Click `Add more` again.

***Some explanation of Javascript and HTML***

A field has id of the form 'field-x-instance', where x is a number/index of the field.

While removing a field, I'm reducing the index of all fields present after the removed instance. To achieve this, I'm modifying properties such as `id, for, name` to use index-1 in the attribute, where index is the current index of the field being modified.

While adding a new field, I'm cloning a hidden template field that I have put in the DOM with id as 'field-_-instance' and then replacing the underscore with appropriate index (=number of fields currently present).

***Investigation so far***

Based on my investigation, the problem doesn't occur if I assign a new index every time to the newly added field. To achieve this I created a monotonically increasing counter and used it to modify the id/for/name of the new field.

The removing of the fields works fine. The indices are adjusted appropriately. It's only when I'm adding a new field, does the problem show up randomly, provided I'm using current number of fields as the index of the new form (0 based indexing)

***CODE***

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
  // Add select2 to select tags when html is first loaded
  let fieldsContainer = document.getElementById('fields-container');
  let selectTags = fieldsContainer.querySelectorAll('select');
  for (let selectTag of selectTags) {
    $(selectTag).select2();
  }

  // Remove functionality.
  fieldsContainer.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!event.target.classList.contains('remove')) {
      return false;
    }

    let currentElement = event.target;
    let field = currentElement.closest('.field-instance');
    let fieldIndex = field.dataset.index;

    field.remove();

    adjustIndices(fieldIndex);
  });

  // Add functionality
  addButton = document.getElementById('add');
  addButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    // clone template field
    let templateField = document.getElementById('field-_-instance');
    let newField = templateField.cloneNode(true);

    // find what should be the index and update the template field with the index.
    let lastField = document.getElementById('fields-container').querySelector('.field-instance:last-child');
    let lastFieldIndex = parseInt(lastField.dataset.index);

    updateFieldWithNewIndex(newField, /(-)_(-)/, lastFieldIndex + 1);

    // insert the element in the DOM
    fieldsContainer.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', newField);

    newField.classList.remove('is_hidden');
    newField.classList.add('field-instance');

    // Initialize select2 on this new element
    let selectTags = newField.querySelectorAll('select');
    for (let selectTag of selectTags) {
      $(selectTag).select2();
    }
  });
});

// function to reduce index by 1 for all fields that are after the removed field.
function adjustIndices(removedIndex) {
  let fieldInstances = document.querySelectorAll('.field-instance');
  for (let fieldInstance of fieldInstances) {
    let index = fieldInstance.dataset.index;
    if (index < removedIndex) {
      continue;
    }
    updateFieldWithNewIndex(fieldInstance, /(-)\d+(-)/, index - 1);
  }
}

// function to replace the index with a new index
function updateFieldWithNewIndex(field, regex, newIndex) {
  field.id = field.id.replace(regex, `$1${newIndex}$2`);
  field.dataset.index = newIndex;

  for (let elem of field.querySelectorAll('*')) {
    for (let attr of ['id', 'name', 'for']) {
      if (elem.hasAttribute(attr)) {
        elem.setAttribute(attr, elem.getAttribute(attr).replace(/(-)_(-)/, `$1${newIndex}$2`));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.is_hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <form action="" method="post">
    <div id="fields-container">
      <div id="field-0-instance" class="field-instance" data-index="0">
        <label for="field-0-phone_number">Phone number</label>
        <select id="field-0-phone_number" name="field-0-phone_number" data-select2-id="field-0-phone_number" tabindex="-1" class="select2-hidden-accessible" aria-hidden="true">
          <option value="" data-select2-id="2">None</option>
          <option value="1">1234</option>
          <option value="2">2345</option>
          <option value="3">3456</option>
        </select><span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="1" style="width: 60px;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-labelledby="select2-field-0-phone_number-container"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-field-0-phone_number-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" title="None">None</span>
        <span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span>
        </span>
        </span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a id="add" href="#">Add more</a>
  </form>
  <div id="field-_-instance" class="is_hidden" data-index="_">
    <label for="field-_-phone_number">Phone number</label>
    <select id="field-_-phone_number" name="field-_-phone_number">
      <option value="">None</option>
      <option value="1">1234</option>
      <option value="2">2345</option>
      <option value="3">3456</option>
    </select>
    <a class="remove" href="#">Remove</a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].  If you get stuck, post a ***[mcve]*** of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. As far as I can see there is no need for any python or flask here. Please just post RELEVANT RENDERED HTML and RELEVANT JS frameworks from CDN plus necessary CSS. There is no way I will download your code, create a virtual environment and play around. Post a running example here instead

Comment: Suggestions: Only have ONE place where you have `$(selectTag).select2();`  - you could for example destroy first. My guess is the renumbering messes the select2. Why do you even need a numbering? Use a `phone[]` array name. Also don't mix jQuery and DOM access. This is just silly and error prone: `let selectTags = newForm.querySelectorAll('select'); for(let selectTag of selectTags){ $(selectTag).select2(); }`.

Comment: @mplungjan Thank you so much for the guidance. I have edited the question as per your suggestions. 
Regarding why I'm not using phone[], that is because these names are generated by flask/jinja in my original application. I'm using a FieldList as a field in my form, and flask generates names of the format '<fieldListName>-<index>-<field>'

Also, I couldn't find a good way to initialise select2 on an element without using jQuery. I'm new to JS and jQuery. Could you please guide me? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It is not random

To recreate click add, add, add and remove one from the middle and click add again.

Anyway, here is a rewrite that is much simpler and DRYer

Note I REMOVED the select2 rendered code from just after your plain select. It was not useful to have at all.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
  let fieldsContainer = document.getElementById('fields-container');
  fieldsContainer.querySelectorAll('select').forEach(select => $(selectTag).select2());
  const templateDiv = document.getElementById("fieldInstanceTemplate");
  // Remove functionality.
  fieldsContainer.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let currentElement = event.target.closest("a");
    if (!currentElement.matches('.remove')) return false;
    let field = currentElement.closest('.field-instance');
    let fieldIndex = field.dataset.index;
    field.remove();
  });

  // Add functionality
  addButton = document.getElementById('add');
  addButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    // clone template field
    let newField = templateDiv.content.cloneNode(true);
    // insert the element in the DOM
    fieldsContainer.append(newField);
    const allInstances = fieldsContainer.querySelectorAll(".field-instance")
    allInstances.forEach((div, i) => { 
      div.querySelector(".remove").hidden = i === 0; 
      div.querySelectorAll("[id^='field-']").forEach(elem => { 
        ['id', 'name', 'for'].forEach(thisattr => {
          let attr = elem.getAttribute(thisattr);
          if (attr) elem.setAttribute(thisattr, attr.replace(/-.*?-/, `-${i}-`)) // replace first occurrence
        })
      })
    });
    // Initialize select2 on this new element
    [...allInstances].pop().querySelectorAll("select").forEach(selectTag =>     $(selectTag).select2());
  });  
  addButton.click()
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <form action="" method="post">
    <div id="fields-container">
    </div>
    <a id="add" href="#">Add more</a>
  </form>
  <template id="fieldInstanceTemplate">
      <div class="field-instance">
        <label>Phone number
        <select id="field-_-phone_number" name="field-_-phone_number">
          <option value="">None</option>
          <option value="1">1234</option>
          <option value="2">2345</option>
          <option value="3">3456</option>
        </select></label>
        <a class="remove" href="#" hidden>Remove</a>
      </div>
</template>
</body>

</html>
```